# Do there exist nontrivial quotient groups of arbitrary finite order?

Tags: group-theory

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, does there exist a group $G$ and a nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ such that $\left\vert G/N\right\vert =n$?

Comment: Sure, $G = \mathbb{Z}_{2n}$ and $N = \{0, n\}$.

Comment: Not only is every natural number the size of a quotient group, but every group is isomorphic to a quotient group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a direct product $G_1\times G_2$ of two groups the subset
$\{(g,e)\mid g\in G_1\}$ is always a normal subgroup (isomorphic to $G_1$). Hence quotienting by it gives $G_2$. So any group (whatever be its order) can be obtained as  $G/N$ for suitable $G$ and a suitable normal subgroup $N$ there.